# JS - Bloquear botão quando os inputs não atendem a um requisito

Tags: javascript, html

Bem, estou tentando bloquear um botao quando os inputs não estiverem preenchidos da forma mas não consigo, já vi vários exemplos de códigos que funcionaram mas até quando tento copiar, dão o mesmo erro.
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**

*html*

```
    <fieldset id="fie">

    <legend>LOGIN</legend>
    <div class='campo'>
        <label for="login">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
        <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" required>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn" >Login</button>

    </fieldset>
```

*JavaScript*

```
  let btn = document.querySelector('btn');
  let login = document.querySelector('login');
  let senha = document.querySelector('senha');

  login.addEventListener('keyup', verificar(login));
  senha.addEventListener('keyup', verificar(senha));

  function verificar(verificado){

      if(verificado.value.lenght < 3 ){
          btn.disabled = true;
      }else{
          btn.disabled = false;
      }

  }
```

Comment: O método querySelector aceita uma micro-linguagem semelhante ao jQuery. Acredito que você quer selecionar elementos por classe, então tem de botar um ponto na frente de cada nome e.g. querySelector('.btn'). Se fosse selecionar por id teria de colocar a # na frente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo pois o seletor não está encontrando o input desejado e retornando o valor como "null", para resolver basta acrecentar um "." antes dos seletores para ele entender que está buscando o elemento pela classe. Por exemplo, `let login = document.querySelector('.login');`

Para seu código funcionar da forma que deseja, você pode utilizar o `onkeyup` nos dois input para chamar uma única função que valida se os dois campos possuem mais de 3 caracteres.

Modifiquei um pouco seu html e alterei um pouco a lógica do seu script. Vou comentar as alterações para você entender melhor. Segue:

HMTL:

```
<fieldset id="fie">
    
    // Para ambos os inputs, adicionei uma classe para encontrar o input pelo querySelector,
    // e adicionei "onkeyup" para chamar a função "validaCampo()" quando pressionado alguma tecla.
    <legend>LOGIN</legend>
    <div class='campo'>
        <label for="login">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="login" required onkeyup="validaCampo()">
    </div>          

    <div class="campo">
        <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="senha" required onkeyup="validaCampo()"> 
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn" >Login</button>

</fieldset>
```

Script:

```
 let btn   = document.querySelector('.btn');   //coloquei um "."  para localizar pela classe "btn"
 let login = document.querySelector('.login'); //coloquei um "."  para localizar pela classe "login"
 let senha = document.querySelector('.senha'); //coloquei um "."  para localizar pela classe "senha"

 btn.disabled = true; // Aqui setei inicialmente o botão como "disabled" fora da function,
                      // ou seja, quando carregamos o site o botão é desabilitado.

 function validaCampo(){
      // A condição é a seguinte: Para liberar o botão, os dois campos precisam
      // possuir mais de 3 caracteres.
    if(login.value.length > 3 && senha.value.length > 3){
        
        btn.disabled = false; // Então aqui habilitamos o botão.

    }else {
     // Caso apagamos algum caractere, e passar a ter 3 ou menos, ele desabilita o botão novamente.
        btn.disabled = true; 
    
    }
  }
```